# Distribution in Pair Plot using Seaborn in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

In the Seaborn package of python, when we give the following code :

```
seaborn.pairplot(ds, hue="species")
```

we get a pairplot. In this pairplot, distribution is shown.

> What kind of distribution is shown?

I googled it and found that it is uni-variate distribution. But still, I want to know what kind of uni-variate distribution is used in specific.

Can someone help me , because I am new to machine learning, please..

Comment: In the example you give the code will return the kernel density estimator of the observations for a given variable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation. In the simplest terms possible, in this scenario KDE can be thought of as a smooth histogram, - it is a probability density function of the predicted values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Univariate can be broken down into 'uni' and 'variate', translated to 'one variable'. As seen in the image below, each axis shows the correlation between the variables named on the x and y-axis for that plot. The diagonal would plot the same variable against itself resulting in a straight line. Since that would be useless information, they show the histogram of that data instead.

The histogram shows the distribution of values in your data. It does not inherently show a normal distribution, poison distribution or any particular distribution. It is up to the user to be able to look at the data and how it is distributed to determine the kind of distribution the data follows.

[image]